# Can not write ActionListener in JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Please help me solve my problem. My problems are with this code in `java`.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {     
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {               
        text.append("hello\n");
   }
});
```

and error is :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at swing.Mainframe.<init>(Mainframe.java:23)
at swing.Swing$1.run(Swing.java:11)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: if my description isn't enough please ask your question

Comment: Your description is definitely not enough. Please add some code to show some sort of an attempt at fixing the problem.

Comment: What is `text`? Presumably this variable is null? That's what you need to fix.

Comment: The code provided is not enough. But, as mentioned, you need to make sure that the variables being used are not null. Make sure you are creating an instance of your button using JButton button = new JButton("MyButton"); and also make sure that the variable text has been instanced as well, if it is a JTextArea probably, you would like to have: JTextArea text = new JTextArea(); Otherwise you will crash your application with a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Write this before you code:

```
button = new JButton();
```

It seems like your variable isn't been initialized yet.

Or either the `text` variable